# how to pass the case statements in to .selectExpr("*", "all case statements") spark code, from external file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below case statement in sql file

note - it is just a sample statement and i saved it as col_sql.sql

```
"CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN ONE END AS INT_VAL"
, "CASE WHEN a = 'DE' THEN 'APHABET' AS STR_VAL"
```

In spark scala code

Im getting the col_sql.sql as per below

```
val col_file = "dir/path/col_sql.sql"
val col_query = readFile(col_file) --- It is internal converted as string using .mkString
```

Then passing it to my select query in spark code

```
.selectExpr("*", col_query )
```

Expectation --

My expectation is when my spark job is running the case statement should be passed in .selectExpr() function as it is given in sql file, like below it should be passed.
When manually running in spark2-shell it is working correctly but in spark2-summit job it throwing parserDriver error .
Kindly assit me on this.

```
.selectExpr("*", "CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN ONE END AS INT_VAL", "CASE WHEN a = 'DE' THEN 'APHABET' AS STR_VAL")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each argument in `selectExpr` should resolve to one column (see examples [in the doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#selectExpr(exprs:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)). In this case you will have to split the expression read from the file, e.g.:

```scala
// Example given the complete string, you could split already when reading the file
val col_query = "\"CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN ONE END AS INT_VAL\", \"CASE WHEN a = 'DE' THEN 'APHABET' AS STR_VAL\""
val cols_queries = col_query.split(",").map(x => x.trim().stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\""))

df.selectExpr("*", cols_queries: _*) // to expand the list into arguments
```